# Difference between echo -e "<string>" and echo $"<string>"

Tags: command-line, bash

What is the defference between using

```
echo -e "Hello\nWorld"
```

and

```
echo $"Hello\nWorld"
```

don't they both output:

```
Hello
World
```

Comment: Did you try it? The second one outputs `Hello\nWorld`. You need the `-e` switch to interpret escape characters.

Comment: For the second one, I suspect that you meant to write it with single quotes, `echo $'Hello\nWorld'`, which will print out on two lines under bash.

Comment: @becko, yes I tried it and they both output the same exact thing.

Comment: Also relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189787/difference-between-echo-and-echo-e

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`echo -e` and `echo $'...'` are both similar in that they support the following escape sequences:

```
  \a     alert (bell)
  \b     backspace
  \e
  \E     an escape character
  \f     form feed
  \n     new line
  \r     carriage return
  \t     horizontal tab
  \v     vertical tab
  \\     backslash
  \0nnn  the eight-bit character whose value is the octal value nnn (zero to three octal digits)
  \xHH   the eight-bit character whose value is the hexadecimal value HH (one or two hex digits)
  \uHHHH the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is the hexadecimal value HHHH (one to four hex digits)
  \UHHHHHHHH
         the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is the hexadecimal value HHHHHHHH (one to eight hex digits)
```

They do have differences.  In addition to the above, `echo -e` supports:

```
  \c     suppress further output
  \0nnn  the eight-bit character whose value is the octal value nnn (zero to three octal digits)
```

By contrast, `$'....'` supports:

> ```
>  \'     single quote
>  \"     double quote
>  \nnn   the eight-bit character whose value is the octal value nnn (one to three digits)
>  \cx    a control-x character
> ```

Observe that, between the two, the `\c` extensions are incompatible:

```
$ echo -e  'start\n\cIstop'
start
$ echo  $'start\n\cIstop'
start
        stop
```

For `echo -e` above, `\c` suppresses further output, thereby ignoring the `Istop`.  By contrast, for `$'...'`, the `\cI` is interpreted as a tab.

#### The visually-similar form: `$"..."`

By contrast with `$'...'`, the function of `$"..."` is quite different.  It will cause the string it contains to be translated according to the current locale.

#### The `echo -e` controversy

`echo -e` is not universally supported by shells and many regard the `-e` option as a design mistake.  Observe:

```
$ ls
-e  -n
$ echo *
$ printf "%s\n" *
-e
-n
```

As you can see, if what you are printing with `echo` starts with a dash, the results can be unexpected.  Unless you are sure that the first string that you will print with `echo` does not start with a dash, you are likely better off using `printf`.

For these reasons, [the POSIX standard concludes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html#tag_20_37_16):

> New applications are encouraged to use printf instead of echo.

Chet Ramey, who has maintained `bash` for the last 22 years, [agrees](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2013-04/msg00008.html):

> [N]ew code should use printf.

Comment: Also worth noting that both [Chet](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2013-04/msg00008.html) and [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html#tag_20_37_16) recommend using `printf` rather than `echo`

Comment: @geirha Very good points.  Answer updated.

Comment: The problem of unexpected options from globs (like `*`) isn't actually specific to `echo`. It happens with any command that recognizes short or long options (written in the traditional way) and takes filename operands, [including `ls`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8578017/). Arguably the situation is a little worse with `echo` since (as your source mentions) `echo` doesn't typically accept `--` to indicate the end of options, whereas one can write commands like `ls -- *l`. (And really one ought usually to write commands that way, when using globs that begin with `*` or `-`, especially in scripts.)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer, I have an excercise for my Operating Systems course and I needed to print out some text using the `\n` escape sequence, so in fact it doesn't matter if I use `echo -e '...'`, `echo $'...'`, or `echo $"..."`